# Feeding "mixed" NMEA to NTP for time correction

Tags: raspberry-pi, ntp, ntpd, gpsd

I am trying to correct the time on my Raspberry pi by feeding NTPD with GPS nmea data (via serial) and PPS (via GPIO pin) using the following tutorial via shared memory "SHM".

http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/raspberry-pi3-gps-time.html

The NMEA serial stream I have also outputs raw GPS data combined with NMEA since I need the raw data for another purpose.  Can NTPD differentiate the NMEA data only even when other data are present?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the tutorial, the GPS actually communicates with `gpsd`, which then passes only the time information to `ntpd` through a shared-memory interface. Note that the `ntpd` reference clock driver pseudo-IP for the NMEA driver (`127.127.20.*`) is not used in the tutorial at all. Only the SHM driver of `ntpd` is used, so `ntpd` won't be seeing NMEA data at all if set up according to the tutorial.

`gpsd` certainly can handle multiple clients using GPS data for other purposes, and it can decode both NMEA and various raw binary GPS data formats. It's hard to say for sure without knowing more details about your specific GPS serial data stream, but since `gpsd` seems to be very robustly programmed and has wide support for various GPSs, there is a good chance it will handle your datastream just fine.